# How To Edit/Delete Stored Data From Database In PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, error-handling

**EDIT**
I have a mysql table with fields as follows:

Products - serial, name, description, price, picture.

the viewproducts.php page is as follows:

```
    <?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ")
or die(mysql_error()); ;

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
       echo 'There Arent Any Products';
    } else {

echo "<table border='0'><table border='1' width=100%><tr><th>Product Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Price</th><th>Image</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th>";
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['name']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['description']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>£" .  $info['price']." </td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<img src='../getImage.php?id=" . $info['serial'] ."'/></td>";

        echo '<td> <a href="edit.php?product_id="' . $info['serial'] . '">Edit</a></td>';

}
    }
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

my edit.php page looks like this:

```
 <?php

$product_id = $_GET['serial'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE serial = '$product_id'")
or die(mysql_error()); ;

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
       echo 'There Arent Any Products';
    } else {

echo "<table border='0'><table border='1' width=100%><tr><th>Product Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Price</th><th>Image</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th>";
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['name']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['description']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>£" .  $info['price']." </td>";
        echo "<td>" . "<img src='../getImage.php?id=" . $info['serial'] ."'/></td>";

}
    }
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

when i click on edit from thr viewproducts.php page, it goes to edit.php page where nothing is showing up. the serial id on the address bar is coming up as follows:

```
 http://www.********.com/****/admin/edit.php?product_id=
```

I want to be able to edit any product clicked on from the viewproduct.php page and transfered to edit.php page. I dont think my edit.php page is set up corretly.

Please help,

Thanks

Comment: This mean that you have problem with $info['serial']. Please do a var_dump($info['serial']); just before the edit line and see what you get. P.S. Don't forget to sanitize the input or you'll have a lot of problem with sql injection.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa sorry i am new to php and so lost with what you are saying. i put var_dump($info['serial']); before the edit line and viewed it on my server. it came up with string(2) "16" string(2) "15" string(2) "40"  before i had even clicked on edit

Comment: oh ok..so what do i do now? i cannot get the products to appear on edit.php to allow the admin to edit its contents?

Comment: I got it. When you have a parameter, to retrieve it you have not to get it using the name in the database but the name of the parameter itself. In your case, you're trying to access the param in this way $_GET['serial']; but you should use $_GET['product_id']; instead.

Comment: ok so i should hve the following? $_GET['product_id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE serial = $_GET['product_id']")

Comment: lol sorry still not working...this is my code: $_GET['product_id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE serial = '$_GET[product_id]'")

Comment: Wrong. $id = $_GET['product_id']; $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE serial = '$id'");

Comment: Because your html is broken. The href attribute of the <a> should not end before echoing the id. So you should not have <a href="edit.php?product_id="' but <a href="edit.php?product_id='

Comment: sorry to be such a pain in the arse, but its still not working!!!

Comment: this is the echo statement:   echo '<td> <a href="edit.php?product_id=' . $info['serial'] . '">Edit</a></td>';

Comment: Sorry man but I can't do your tutor lifelong. I gave you good tips and now you're on the right path. You've to start to walk alone and to learn how to debug you script.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass via `$_GET` the id of the product and then, in the edit/delete page, retrieve that parameter. Obviously you have to **sanitize the input properly** before using it. For example, the link of the each product should look like this:

```
echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id="' . $info['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
```

In the edit page you should have something like:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
// For example, if the product id is an integer
// you can sanitize it doing this
$id = (int) $id
```

Comment: i have $product_id = $_GET['serial']; $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE serial = '$product_id'") but nothing is showing up on my table. when i access this on the web, the serial id is empty

Comment: @Jahed Update your question showing us how you change the code.

Comment: sorry about that...i have now edited my main post. I hope it makes much more sense now

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it as an argument to your php file in wich you want to edit/delete the product:

```
<a href="edit.php?product_id=<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>">Edit Product</a>
```

Then in your `edit.php` you will pick up the id of the product and load it's data from the database.

```
[edit.php]
$product_id = isset($_GET['product_id']) ? intval($_GET['product_id']) : null;
if(!$product_id) {
    exit();
}
// query your database for the product
$row = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE product_id = $product_id");
// then you output your html with fields populated from the result from the database
```